# How does this control architecture script look?

Tags: php, oop, coding-style, feedback

I am looking for feedback on my control architecture script (included below).  Specifically, I am looking for feedback regarding the script's design, organization, commenting, and formatting.  I enjoy php programming as a hobby, and am looking to learn where I can improve my code.

Thanks in advance!

```
class FrontController extends ActionController {

//Declaring variable(s)
private static $instance;
protected $controller;

//Class construct method
public function __construct() {}

//Starts new instance of this class with a singleton pattern
public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function dispatch($throwExceptions = false) {

    /* Checks for the GET variables $module and $action, and, if present,
     * strips them down with a regular expression function with a white
     * list of allowed characters, removing anything that is not a letter,
     * number, underscore or hyphen.
     */
    $regex  = '/[^-_A-z0-9]+/';
    $module = isset($_GET['module']) ? preg_replace($regex, '', $_GET['module']) : 'home';
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? preg_replace($regex, '', $_GET['action']) : 'frontpage';

    /* Generates Actions class filename (example: HomeActions) and path to
     * that class (example: home/HomeActions.php), checks if $file is a
     * valid file, and then, if so, requires that file.
     */
    $class = ucfirst($module) . 'Actions';
    $file  = $this->pageDir . '/' . $module . '/' . $class . '.php';

    try {

        //Checks for existance of file
        if (!is_file($file)) {
            throw new Exception('File not found!');
        }

        //Includes file
        require_once $file;

        /* Creates a new instance of the Actions class (example: $controller
         * = new HomeActions();), and passes the registry variable to the
         * ActionController class.
         */
        $controller = new $class();
        $controller->setRegistry($this->registry);

        //Trys the setModule method in the ActionController class
        $controller->setModule($module);

        /* The ActionController dispatchAction method checks if the method
         * exists, then runs the displayView function in the
         * ActionController class.
         */    
        $controller->dispatchAction($action);

    } catch(Exception $error) {

        /* An exception has occurred, and will be displayed if
         * $throwExceptions is set to true.
         */
        if($throwExceptions) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}
}

abstract class ActionController {

//Declaring variable(s)
protected $registry;
protected $module;
protected $registryItems = array();

//Class construct method
public function __construct(){}

public function setRegistry($registry) {

    //Sets the registry object
    $this->registry = $registry;

    /* Once the registry is loaded, the controller root directory path is
     * set from the registry.  This path is needed for the controller
     * classes to work properly.
     */
    $this->setPageDir();
}

//Sets the controller root directory from the value stored in the registry
public function setPageDir() {
    $this->pageDir = $this->registry->get('pageDir');
}

//Sets the module
public function setModule($module) {
    $this->module = $module;
}

//Gets the module
public function getModule() {
    return $this->module;
}

/* Checks for actionMethod in the Actions class (example: doFrontpage()
 * within home/HomeActions.php) with the method_exists function and, if
 * present, the actionMethod and displayView functions are executed.
 */  
public function dispatchAction($action) {
    $actionMethod = 'do' . ucfirst($action);
    if (!method_exists($this, $actionMethod)) {
        throw new Exception('Action not found!');
    }
    $this->$actionMethod();
    $this->displayView($action);
}

public function displayView($action) {
    if (!is_file($this->pageDir . '/' . $this->getModule() . '/' . $action . 'View.php')) {
        throw new Exception('View not found!');
    }

    //Sets $this->actionView to the path of the action View file
    $this->actionView = $this->pageDir . '/' . $this->getModule() . '/' . $action . 'View.php';

    //Sets path of the action View file into the registry
    $this->registry->set('actionView', $this->actionView);

    //Includes template file within which the action View file is included
    require_once $this->pageDir . '/default.tpl';
}
}

class Registry {

//Declaring variables
private $store;

//Class constructor
public function __construct() {}

//Sets registry variable
public function set($label, $object) {
    $this->store[$label] = $object;
}

//Gets registry variable    
public function get($label) {
    if(isset($this->store[$label])) {
        return $this->store[$label];
    } else {
        return false;          
    }
}

//Adds outside array of registry values to $this->store array
public function addRegistryArray($registryItems) {
    foreach ($registryItems as $key => $value) {
        $this->set($key, $value);
    }
}

//Returns registry array
public function getRegistryArray() {
    return $this->store;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a detailed look on your code:

Try to write code that is self-explanatory by using meaningful function and variable names. Only use comments where the purpose or the functioning of your code is not clear. E.g.

```
//Declaring variable(s)
//Class construct method
//Checks for existance of file
//Includes file
```

are useless comments because the code itself is already clear enough.

A book worth reading: [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Comment: I concur with this answer. You'll run into many people with wild beliefs in comments ranging from "Your code should be 50% comments, and 50% code" (a professor when I was in school) to "Programmers don't need comments, that's just there for people who can't read code" (someone on DreamInCode). Comments should explain things that are confusing, and save time. You don't need to explain how to program, you don't need to be overly verbose, but you need to explain generally what your code is trying to do, and anything that's really complicated is worth explaining.

Comment: I have requested that book from my library.  I will also try to remove the comments you pointed out.  Any other feedback?  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am torn between closevoting as too localized and wanting to comment on the code. Also, it's too much code to wade through now, so I will comment only a few things:

**1) Documentation style**

Why not use an established documentation format, like [PHPDoc](http://manual.phpdoc.org/)?

**2) Formatting**

is consistent as far as I can see, but I suggest to use a coding convention that is in wide use, like that of [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) or ZF (which is based on PEAR) instead of doing your own (yours is close to PEAR anyway, so you might as well adopt it completely).

**3) Singleton pattern**

In order for the [Singleton](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) to work it has to have a private __contruct and __clone method. But I suggest not to use it at all. Many people believe the Singleton is an AntiPattern. There are a number of questions on SO discussing the disadvantages of the Singleton pattern, so have a look around. If there should be only one instance, then simply dont instantiate a second one. If you need to access the FrontController in other classes, [inject it](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection).

**4) Method length**

I probably would try to shorten the `dispatch` method. Basically, if you describe what a  method does and you have to use an *and* to do so, that part should go into it's own method. Try to make methods into small discrete units. That will make [UnitTesting](http://www.phpunit.de/) easier as well.

**5) Separation of Concerns**

I am not sure why the [FrontController](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) extends from ActionController. There is no other classes that extent it, butI suppose the classes the FrontController instantiates are subclasses of ActionController too. But the FrontController, while named a controller, does different things than the [PageControllers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html), so I'd probably keep them separated.

On a sidenote, if you are interested in increasing the quality of your code, have a look at the slides and tools given at http://phpqatools.org/

Comment: I thought I was conforming to the PEAR conventions.  In what way am I not?  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Which specific methods would you recommend shortening?

Comment: @Drew For instance, there should be indentation after the class opening. Curly braces in functions and class definitions should start at the new line. Private members, but not proteced, should be preceded by a single underscore. You can use PHP_CodeSniffer to see where it's off.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very remeiscent of [CakePhp](http://cakephp.org/).  I'd recommend checking that out, it does all of this work with App::import() and a File class that wraps the filesystem.  It's tested by a community on different versions and OSes, it will in fact save you time.